# Creating API Gateway to HTTP to Private IP in AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to AWS. 
I have an application say "Apln1" running in the EC2, which is having private and public IP.
Also, I have another application say "Apln2" running in another server which will do an HTTP post to the application. Currently, Apln2 is doing POST to the public IP in EC2.

I need to remove the public IP and use Private Ip instead.

Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Alpn1 and Alpn2 are running two different VPC ( hence can not connect using private IP).  You can use AWS PrivateLink technology ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpce-interface.html ) to connect two VPCs , without using public IP.

Comment: Apln s not in AWS, it is an out side server trying to connect to the EC2.

Comment: I just moved the app1 to lambda and connected through api gateway. this gave me more security. Thanks